# Extract marked areas in image by same sized surrounding rectangles

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to extract one or more areas of an image which are marked on the image with an arbitrary shape (the shape edges have always the same color - red). The marked areas all have about the same size (not excactly) and I would like to have the cut out rectangles to have the same result size.

Can you give me a hint how to do this? I guess one could use opencv for this task in python, but I'm not familiar with it, so thanks for your help!

edit: added an example image, the goal would be to extract the red areas by rectangles of the same size.
[image: example image]

Comment: A picture is worth a 1,000 words.

Comment: What do you mean by *"rectangles of the same size"*? The same size as the rectangles marked in the image? Or rectangles the same size as each other (regardless of the size in the image)? Did you think of using a colour that contrasts better with your image content - red on orangey-red is hardly ideal? What about blue?

Comment: By rectangles of the same size I mean that the above example would lead to 3 rectangles each of same size (I need to choose a Standard size big enough for the areas) and with the marked Red area in its centers.

Comment: What if you get another image with a very large rectangle? Is that the new *"Standard size"*?

Comment: Suppose that all marked areas don't exceed the big enough defined rectangle size. My underlying question here is how to get the locations of the marked areas.

Comment: As I do know the exact color of the surroundings probably by some masking?

Comment: You are not really doing yourself any favours here. Firstly, red contrasts poorly as a marker colour with your image. Secondly, red is the hardest colour to find when you convert to HSV colourspace because it shows up as discontinuous Hues from 350 through 359, AND 0..10. Thirdly, you are using JPEG image format which is lossy, so there are actually no pure red, i.e. `rgb(255,0,0)` pixels in your image, the nearest you have is `rgb(255,11,30)`. So, I will ask again - could you use blue as your marker colour and could you save as PNG after marking?

Comment: The above image is an example and not the actual image I use. The real image is bmp and grayscale with red markings. Actually I would just like to know the general approach for such a case. And you could also suppose that the marking ist blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the gray input with red shapes drawn
- Threshold on the red color of the shapes
- Apply morphology close to ensure the shapes are continous outlines with no gaps
- Get the external contours and their bounding boxes
- Compute the centers of each bounding box and save in list and also the maximum width and height of all the bounding boxes.
- For each center and the maximum width and height, crop the input image and save

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('monet_shapes.png')

# threshold on red regions
lowerBound = np.array([0, 0, 150]);
upperBound = np.array([100, 100, 255]);
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lowerBound, upperBound);

# apply morphology to ensure regions are continuous outlines and no gaps
kernel = np.ones((9,9), np.uint8)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)    

# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
wmax = 0
hmax = 0
# get bounding boxes and max width and max height from all boxes and centers
centers = []
for cntr in contours:
    # get bounding boxes
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    cx = x + w // 2
    cy = y + h // 2
    cent = [cx,cy]
    centers.append(cent)
    if w > wmax:
        wmax = w
    if h > hmax:
        hmax = h

print(wmax,hmax)

# show thresh and result    
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save threshold
cv2.imwrite("monet_shapes_thresh.png",thresh)

# crop bounding boxes of size maxw, maxh about centers and save
i = 1
for cent in centers:
    cx = cent[0]
    cy = cent[1]    
    box = img[cy-hmax//2:cy+hmax//2, cx-wmax//2:cx+wmax//2]
    cv2.imwrite("blackbox_result_{0}.png".format(i),box)
    i = i + 1
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Resulting 5 cropped regions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination!